# How to access semaphore from child program

Tags: c, windows, process, semaphore

The following program, compiled as a.exe and invoked as "a.exe parent", prints "bad." How do I make it print "good?"

Edit: GetLastError returns 2

```
/* Inter-process Communication */
#include <windows.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static HANDLE semaphore;
static STARTUPINFO StartupInfo;
static PROCESS_INFORMATION ProcessInfo;
static char *Args = "a.exe child";

int createChildProcess()
{
  memset(&StartupInfo, 0, sizeof(StartupInfo));
  StartupInfo.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO);
  StartupInfo.dwFlags = STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
  StartupInfo.wShowWindow = SW_HIDE;

  if (!CreateProcess( NULL, Args, NULL, NULL, FALSE,
                      0,
                      NULL,
                      NULL,
                      &StartupInfo,
                      &ProcessInfo))
    {
      return 0;
    }

  return 1;
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{

  if(!strcmp(argv[1], "child")) {
    semaphore = OpenSemaphore(SYNCHRONIZE|SEMAPHORE_MODIFY_STATE,
                              FALSE, "Global\\EZShare");
    if(semaphore==NULL) {
      printf("bad\n");
    }
    else {
      printf("good\n");
    }

  }
  else {
    semaphore = CreateSemaphore(NULL, 1, 1, "Global\\EZShare");
    assert(semaphore!=NULL);
    assert(createChildProcess());
  }
}
```

Comment: What about printing out the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parent process exits earlier than the child process opens the semaphore, and when it happens, the semaphore is destroyed. Add `Sleep(10000)` before exiting `main()` in parent, and you will get "good" (for real program, it's better to wait for the child process than to sleep).

Comment: Another option would be to make the semaphore handle inheritable (and set the inherit handles flag in the call to CreateProcess) so that the child process inherits a copy of the original handle, forcing the semaphore to remain open.  Of course, in most real-world situations it is preferable for the parent to remain open, but there are edge cases.